# Excel Duplication verification Function

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

So I am trying the spreadsheet to inform me if there are accidental duplicates.
I will show the image first to make explaining easier.

[image]

So what I am trying to do is use a function on the "DUPLICATE VERIFICATION" column that informs me if there is a duplicate.

```
=IF(AND(D2=D2:D9, E2=E2:E9), "DUP","OK")
```

I tried the above but it is not working since I think the Function is not reading"D2:D9" and "E2:E9" as individual words.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

I am very open to VBA if that is the best solution.

Although I normally appreciate any ideas including the ones that require modifying the table in order to fit the requirement, for this specific table I prefer not to since the table is already structured and it is a table that many people use and are used to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: `=IF(COUNTIFS(D$2:D$9,D2,E$2:E$9,E2)>1,"DUP","OK")`

Comment: This is not the question, but you may want to use `=IF(COUNTIFS(D$2:D2,D2,E$2:E2,E2)-1,"DUP","OK")` here. Reason: it'll return `OK` for the first occurance and `DUP` for any next occurance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `COUNTIFS()`

[image]

---

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(D$2:D$9,D2,E$2:E$9,E2)>1,"DUP","OK")
```

---

Comment: Thanks, it works :) (ps, I can only accept your answer after a few min.)

Comment: As you wish no rush here!